# Creating pybind11 module to return a random torch tensor: Undefined symbol error

Tags: c++, cmake, pybind11, libtorch

I'm trying to create a python module using pybind11 to generate a torch tensor. I'm doing this in colaboratory. First, I get the libtorch library from     `wget https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cu102/libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-1.7.1.zip` and     `unzip libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-1.7.1.zip`. Also I do `git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git`.

I have two .cpp files. The first one is **testLibtorch.cpp** containing:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <torch/extension.h>

using torch::Tensor;

Tensor test(int num) {
  Tensor tensor1 = torch::randn({4, 3});
  return tensor1;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(testLibtorch, m) {
    m.doc() = "hello world"; // optional module docstring
    m.def("test", &test, "A function giving torch tensor");

}
```

The second one is **testExe.cpp** containing:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <torch/extension.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << torch::randn({4, 3}) << std::endl;
}
```

I'm writing my own **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
project(torchlibtest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(/content/libtorch)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/content/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

pybind11_add_module(testLibtorch testLibtorch.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testLibtorch PRIVATE "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

target_link_libraries(testLibtorch ${MY_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET testLibtorch PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(testExe testExe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testExe PRIVATE "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET example-app
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:example-app>)
endif (MSVC)
```

Then I successfully cmake and make. However, when I try to import my module testLibtorch, I receive this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9855a0c0e93c> in <module>()
      1 import torch
----> 2 import testLibtorch
      3 print(testLibtorch.test(4))

ImportError: /content/build/testLibtorch.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Z16THPVariable_WrapN2at6TensorE
```

I doubt that I may fail to import class and functions from torch, but the executable from **testExe.cpp** seems to work fine.
Will appreciate solutions to the problem, as well as recommendations and ideas for the task I'm trying to do.